# $f$ is continuous $\iff f(\bar A) \subset \overline{f(A)}$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

*The problem is:*

$f:X\to Y$: any map.

$f$ is continuous $\iff \forall A\subset X, \ f(\bar A) \subset \overline{f(A)}$

*My understanding is:*

Suppose $f$ is continuous.

$\forall A\subset X, A \subset f^{-1}(f(A)) \subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(A))}$

so $f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$ is a closed set (by continuity) containing $A$.

Since $\bar A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$, $\bar A \subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$,

so that $f(\bar A) \subset f(f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})) \subset \overline{f(A)}$.

Conversely, let $F$ be any closed subset of $Y$.

We want to say $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed.

$f(\overline{f^{-1}(F)}) \subset \overline{f(f^{-1}(F))} \subset \overline{F}$,

so that $\overline{f^{-1}(F)} \subset f^{-1}(f(\overline{f^{-1}(F)})) \subset f^{-1}(\overline{F}) = f^{-1}(F)$.

Therefore $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed.

My proof is fine? I think this proof is tedious. Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  This proof looks OK.

Comment: @Raczkowski Thank you!